# Merge two MySQL results columns where one column or the other will be not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to merge the results in column A and column B in one column, less the NULLs, where I am left with the results in column A+B. I *can* guarantee that either A or B contains NULL.

I thought I could accomplish this with something like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(Table1.A, Table2.B) FROM `Table1`
  LEFT JOIN `Table2` ON
    *SOME ARBITRARY CONDITION*;
```

Image of the result I'm trying to get at for visualization:

[image]

Comment: And what does your code produce?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was getting a syntax error believe it or not, granted my actual query was not exactly this at the time. I think AS might have helped or gotten me a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(A, B, "") AS `A+B` FROM tbl
```

It returns the first value that is not NULL. You can use as many values as you like, even a fallback. 
("" empty string in my example)

Or, if you can **not** guarantee that there is only one value and the others are NULL:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(",", A, B) AS `A+B` FROM tbl
```

This would result in "Apple,Pear" (A+B) if are both set, and in "Apple" (A only) or "Pear" (B only) when only one is set.